# libudev how to use poll with the file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux

So, I have an application that I want to be notified of hotplug events on linux. Naturally, I looked at libudev and its [API](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/api-index-full.html). I also found a useful [tutorial](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/) on how to use select() with libudev. Following the tutorial and glancing at the API, I came up with this example program that waits for hotplug events and then outputs some basic information about the device that was just added or removed.

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <libudev.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

udev* hotplug;
udev_monitor* hotplug_monitor;

void init()
{
  // create the udev object
  hotplug = udev_new();
  if(!this->hotplug)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("cannot create udev object");
  }

  // create the udev monitor
  hotplug_monitor = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink(hotplug, "udev");

  // start receiving hotplug events
  udev_monitor_enable_receiving(hotplug_monitor);
}

void deinit()
{
  // destroy the udev monitor
  udev_monitor_unref(hotplug_monitor);

  // destroy the udev object
  udev_unref(hotplug);
}

void run()
{
  // create the poll item
  pollfd items[1];
  items[0].fd = udev_monitor_get_fd(hotplug_monitor);
  items[0].events = POLLIN;
  items[0].revents = 0;

  // while there are hotplug events to process
  while(poll(items, 1, 50) > 0)
  {
    // XXX
    std::cout << "hotplug[ " << items[0].revents << " ]" << std::endl;

    // receive the relevant device
    udev_device* dev = udev_monitor_receive_device(hotplug_monitor);
    if(!dev)
    {
      // error receiving device, skip it
      continue;
    }

    // XXX
    std::cout << "hotplug[" << udev_device_get_action(dev) << "] ";
    std::cout << udev_device_get_devnode(dev) << ",";
    std::cout << udev_device_get_subsystem(dev) << ",";
    std::cout << udev_device_get_devtype(dev) << std::endl;

    // destroy the relevant device
    udev_device_unref(dev);

    // XXX
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    // clear the revents
    items[0].revents = 0;
  }
}

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
  init();

  while(true)
  {
    run();
  }

  deinit();
}
```

Well, it doesn't work. Here's the output I get when I plug in a usb mouse.

```
hotplug[ 1 ]
hotplug[add] /dev/bus/usb/008/002,usb,usb_device
done
hotplug[ 1 ]
hotplug[add]
```

At that point the program freezes and I have to stop it with Ctrl-C. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had to deal with udev events too, but I chose a different path - instead of directly talking to udev using libudev, I spawn an "udevadm" process which reports events to me via stdout. If you use my event loop (which can also work on top of glib/gtk+), you can use my implementation of an udev event listener client. See example http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/examples/ncdudevmanager_test.c

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak That's interesting, but I would prefer to avoid starting another process if I can help it. Besides, if I trust that the tutorial code works with select(), then I don't understand why my code won't work with poll(). But Ill keep this in mind as a backup plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program doesn't actually stop; it continues running, but std::cout gets messed up when you try to print a NULL string (not all events have all properties). A fix is to make the three prints (devnode, subsystem, devtype) conditional.

Comment: oh, i did not consider that. im going to modify it so it only prints non-null strings and see what happens. Still, do you know why I get two events instead of two?

Comment: two events instead of two? You mean instead of one? You get whatever udevd sends. For most devices you plug in, it sends more than one event, for different aspects of the device. You can easily observe entire events (including all properties) by running "/sbin/udevadm monitor --udev --property".

Comment: yeah that was it, I actually get more like 7 but I was only seeing the first two, after that a NULL was messing things up. I guess I didn't really understand how udev events worked. Thanks though, saved me some trouble.